# Each child unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I receive this warning:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
render() {
    const exercises = this.state.Exercises.map(exercise => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>Id: {exercise.Id} </Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>Ripetizioni: {exercise.Reps}</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>Note: {exercise.Notes}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styleButton.button, styleButton.buttonOK]}
            onPress={() => this.checkAttività(exercise.Id)}
          >
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a unique key to your `View`

`<View key={exercise.Id}>`

Answer (score 5):

You should pass a key to the return content like :

```
    const exercises = this.state.Exercises.map(exercise => {
      return (
        <View key={`${exercise.Id}`}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>Id: {exercise.Id} </Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>Ripetizioni: {exercise.Reps}</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>Note: {exercise.Notes}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styleButton.button, styleButton.buttonOK]}
            onPress={() => this.checkAttività(exercise.Id)}
          >
      )
    })
```

Edit: React expect key to be a string

Comment: You should precise that the key should be unique (it's ok with your example)

Answer (score 2):

The error message is quite clear. React wants you to define a value that is unique for each item in the list which should be assigned as a `key` prop to each of the `View` objects.

If you want, you could just pull the index out in the map loop and use that as the key:

```
const exercises = this.state.Exercises.map((exercise, index) => {
  return (
    <View key={`view-${index}`}>
...
```

---

**Please read @JanosVinceller comment below and check the link out for a very good reason to NOT do what I propose here. At the least if it is a list which changes.**

Comment: Note: I did see the `id` attribute on the object, but thought someone in the future might need a more "general" version.

Comment: https://medium.com/@vraa/why-using-an-index-as-key-in-react-is-probably-a-bad-idea-7543de68b17c

Comment: Thank you @JanosVinceller, havent actually noticed that earlier, very good point!